# Associating a number value to a word on a webpage, and then multiplying this by a number on the webpage that follows the word

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
<img src="http://lawyer.gif" />
<a href="http://lawyer.com">lawyer</a> (111)
```

or

```
<img src="http://doctor.gif" />
<a href="http://doctor.com">doctor</a> (222)
```

So there are multiple pages containing html similar to the above. I want to assign a specific value to the occurrence of "lawyer" or "lawyer.gif" or whatever and multiply it by 111 IF lawyer is on the page, and then add this to "doctor" multiplied by 222 IF doctor is on the page. There are a lot of different possible "professions" (~50) so the code here is very simplified. One page could have doctor, lawyer, and fireman while another page could have just dentist. This sum should then be displayed on the page or in a popup or whatever really. The 111 and 222 here come from the number in parentheses in the code, and these numbers change on each page.

I planned on doing this with greasemonkey/javascript but only because of my limited experience with this. So I guess my question is first, is this even possible to do at least somewhat simply and if so, could someone at least give me some hints to get me started? Thanks.

Comment: could you give us a more thorough example? your example is hard to follow especially with variables like blah1 and blah2.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to make it more thorough.. I'll replace blah1/blah2 with other words? Maybe that's all you mean.

Comment: Yeah that actually helped a little (at least for me). Is the HTML being generated via PHP or did you create multiple pages with these different professions? if so, why don't you just put an id with each one and then you can just check if the id exists with javascript

Comment: From where do you get that "*certain value*" which you "*assign to the occurence of "lawyer" or "lawyer.gif"*"?

Comment: The webpages aren't mine so I can't exactly put an id. And the value of "lawyer" would be a constant number so is that important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

1. To deal with a lot of something, use an array: `[blah1, blah2, etc.]`
2. To associate ad-hoc values to ad-hoc labels, use an object:
   `[ {blah1: 3.1}, {blah2: 415}, etc.]`
3. To detect and manipulate things on the page use *jQuery*.
4. To add displays or other elements to the page, also use jQuery.

Putting it all together, here is **a complete script** that does what your question appears to ask.  You can also [**see the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3WX26/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Arbitrary math on arbitrary page values
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var textToValuesArray   = [
    {"doctor": 3}
    , {"lawyer": 5}
    , {"rodeo clown": 7}
    // etc.
];
var targetNodes = $("td.left:has(a)");
var targetText  = targetNodes.text ();
var reportValue = 0;

//-- Loop through the textToValuesArray.
$.each (textToValuesArray, function (index, textToValueObject) {
    var textTerm    = Object.keys (textToValueObject)[0];

    //-- Is the text term in the targeted part of the page?
    var termRegex   = new RegExp(textTerm, 'i'); // Case insensitive
    if (termRegex.test (targetText) ) {
        console.log ("Text '" + textTerm + "' was found!");

        /*-- Given the indicated page structure, targetText will look like:
            "doctor (2)lawyer (4)" etc.
            With the value we want coming one space after the target term
            and in parentheses.

            So, if we split the string on the search term, we get the next
            (number), if any.
        */
        var splitStr    = targetText.split (termRegex);
        if (splitStr  &&  splitStr.length > 1) {
            var multiplierString = splitStr[1].replace (/^\s*\((\d+)\).*$/, "$1");
            if (multiplierString) {
                var multiplierInteger = parseInt (multiplierString, 10);
                if (isNaN (multiplierInteger) ) {
                    console.log ("Multiplier value not found! (2)");
                }
                else {
                    /*-- We found a term and we found its multiplier.
                        Add to the report value.
                    */
                    var termValue   = textToValueObject[textTerm];
                    console.log (
                        "termValue: ", termValue,
                        "   ",
                        "multiplierInteger: ", multiplierInteger
                    );
                    reportValue    += termValue * multiplierInteger
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log ("Multiplier value not found! (1)");
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log ("Split string error!");
        }
    }
} );

console.log ("reportValue: ", reportValue);

$("body").prepend ('<div id="gmReport">The final value was: ' + reportValue + '</div>');
$("#gmReport").css ("background", "orange");
```